# Off canvas when adding Zurb Foundation javascript files separately

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

When I link to foundation.js and foundation.offcanvas.js separately i stead of using the minified, combined version the off canvas menu is not working.

Do I have to call the offcanvas additionally to $().foundation(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call the `foundation()` method once after all the Foundation scripts have been loaded.

Taken from their docs:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
<!-- Other JS plugins can be included here -->

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

If Foundation's Off Canvas still isn't working, it's more likely due to the markup being slightly incorrect than the JS being weird. Make sure you follow the [examples](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html) exactly.

Comment: Hi, it's not the mark up. It works when I use the min.js file from the foundation download. I have to use the debugged eualizer.js from github though. With this file and the single file of foubdation and offcanvas it doesn't work.